# drop-down menu make parent link active when child link is active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, parent-child, navbar

While **scrolling**, the sub-menu link change color when they are active. I want the parent (the menu category) to also change color if one of it's children are active.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">    

      <li class= "nav-item tab-menu-link">
         <div class="tab-menu">
          <a class="nav-link" id="AboutParent">About &#9660;</a>            
          <div class="tab-menu-content" id="AboutTabMenu">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto" >
                        <li class="nav-item tab-menu-content-links">
                            <a class="Subnavnav-link nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#About">About TTCU</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item tab-menu-content-links">
                            <a class="Subnavnav-link  nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Achievements">Achievements</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item tab-menu-content-links">
                            <a class="Subnavnav-link nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Team">Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item tab-menu-content-links">
                            <a class="Subnavnav-link nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#FAQ">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item tab-menu-content-links">
                            <a class="Subnavnav-link nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#Location">Location</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

I tried two methods, with css or JQuery,but both of them are not working:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
if($("#About").hasClass("active")){
    $("#AboutParent").addClass("active");
}
```

});

```
.tab-menu-link:active > a, .tab-menu-link .active  > a {
color: #84bd00;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.tab-menu-content-links a:active, .tab-menu a
{
color:red;
}
```

Change the color of `About &#9660;` if any of the links in .`tab-menu-content-links` are active.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for, except that the parent link doesn't have a href it's only a category so how can I change it's color when child link is active?